# First commit of a existing local repository in Eclipse to empty Github repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I often have the situation that I've created a **Java** project in **Eclipse** and want to upload it to **GitHub**. Itself a very easy task.

For this I create a new empty **GitHub** repository via the webinterface.
Then I have to create a local repository like on the following picture:

---

[image]

---

Then I want to commit and then I get this screen:

---

[image]

---

And I from here the real problem begin. I don't know what it means and it takes many tries until something is working. **I already deleted per accident one time my complete project including source files as I had to delete the local repository!**
 Sometimes I get this error:

---

### [image]

Sometimes I get this error:

---

### [image]

Is this the best way or what do I have to do to just get my local project into a fresh or not existing GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer I can give this:
On the `Push Ref Specifications` screen you have to do like this

---

[image]

---

I still don't know what it means, but this seems to be the best way until now to not get this error.